# Inserting number of rows in a table by using trigger in oracle

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I have two tables in oracle. For a column value in my 1st table, I want to generate that many rows in my 2nd table with an auto increment id. How to do that? For example:

```
Table 1: item_id, number_of_items
Table 2: book_id, item_id, status
```

When I insert a new row in table 1 with values (1, 100), I want to create 100 rows in table 2 with auto generated unique book_id, item_id(same item_id as it is in table 1) and status as "available". Can it be done? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to get auto generated ID for Table 2, you should create a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  table2_seq  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 
START WITH 1 NOCACHE NOORDER  NOCYCLE;
```

Then you should create a trigger like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TABLE1_INSERT
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE1
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..:NEW.number_of_items
    LOOP
      INSERT INTO table2 (book_id, item_id, status)
         VALUES(table2_seq.nextval, :NEW.number_of_items, 'available');
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: It is showing "ERROR at line 5: PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here"

Comment: Thank you so much. But in the output, the book_id and item_id are becoming same. However, I wanted for a particular id, there will be number of book Id's generated. Presently, output is (Book_id, item_id, status) values (1,1,available)/(2,2,available)/(3,3, available) but I want the output to be (1,101,available)/(2,101,available)/(3,101,available). You have really helped me a lot. Please solve this.

Comment: Edited to do what you want. Pls, check :)

Comment: Thank u soooooooooooooooo much. U r a true savior. Initially I was not understanding the loop but now, I am understanding it a little more. Thanks a lot......... :)

Comment: How to do that? I am new to stackoverflow. Infact it is my first question here.